# why i am getting a fatal error when parsing xml file?

Tags: java, xml, exception, try-catch, fatal-error

I am parsing an XML file to java, there is a wrong starting tag in the file. When I run the Code it shows the following error:
[Fatal Error] malformed_routes5.xml:9:26: The element type "WrongTag" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

```
    <Route>
    <FlightNumber>1848</FlightNumber>
    <DayOfWeek>Tue</DayOfWeek>
    <DepartureTime>13:40</DepartureTime>
    <DepartureAirport>Belfast</DepartureAirport>
    <DepartureAirportCode>BFS</DepartureAirportCode>
    <WrongTag>18:05</ArrivalTime>
    <ArrivalAirport>Tenerife-Sur</ArrivalAirport>
    <ArrivalAirportCode>TFS</ArrivalAirportCode>
    <Duration>PT4H25M</Duration>
</Route>
```

this is the file which contains the wrong tag, do i need to add a specific exception in the catch for this kind of error?

```
        catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | IllegalArgumentException ioe) {


        throw new DataLoadingException(ioe);
        //** check the fatal error " The element type "WrongTag" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</WrongTag>". "
        // ************************************************

    }
```

Comment: Do you have control over the XML? Can you fix that tag?

Comment: I don't, My parser load multiple XML files, one of them has the wrong tag, I think i have to add an exception or something like that @MichaelMcKay

Comment: Looks like a `SAXParseException` but you have `SAXException` in the list. It is a possibility that some other class wraps that exception in a Runtime Exception and throws away. Just 2 cents.

Comment: Is it just this one tag that is the issue?  If so, fix the XML before you parse it.  A bad tag is difficult to fix in the general case.  It could be a mistake made in forming the xml but it could also indicate a chunk of the file is missing.

Comment: XML parsers are designed to tell you when the XML is broken; the only thing you can do with broken XML is to fix it. I'm not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: Q: Why the fatal error?  A: Because the XML is broken.  See duplicate link for how to parse bad XML.  If your real Q is how to recover from a fatal error, the answer is that you don't -- that's what ***fatal*** means.  Best you can do is catch the exception, inform caller, and move on -- basic Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your XML is broken. I would catch the exception and send it back to the client OR if I own the code that generates this XML, fix that part of the code.

JAVA is throwing a legit error where `<WrongTag>` isn't being closed by `</WrongTag>` but instead by `<ArrivalTime>`.

Comment: I already know that the file is broken, I am trying to get rid of this error by throwing an exception or something like that, I can't change the XML.

Comment: I guess the question is what would you want the calling code to do in this case? Throw a runtime exception for the user and terminate? Or handle it gracefully saying that the program tried to fix this but failed because one of the tags is broken.

Answer (score 0):

*There is an error at tag:*

```
<Route>
    <FlightNumber>1848</FlightNumber>
    <DayOfWeek>Tue</DayOfWeek>
    <DepartureTime>13:40</DepartureTime>
    <DepartureAirport>Belfast</DepartureAirport>
    <DepartureAirportCode>BFS</DepartureAirportCode>
    <WrongTag>18:05**</WrongTag>**
    <ArrivalAirport>Tenerife-Sur</ArrivalAirport>
    <ArrivalAirportCode>TFS</ArrivalAirportCode>
    <Duration>PT4H25M</Duration>
</Route>
```